# How to copy links in Lotus Notes email

Tags: email

In Outlook email, I can point the mouse over any hyperlink in email body and right click and copy the URL that the hyperlink is pointing to.  How do you do this in Lotus Notes email?  Obviously following the same steps as above does not work.  I'm using Notes 9.0.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Many times, it seen to be an issue with "Default Browser" settings. Try resetting the browser setting as "Set Default Browser" settings Or Uninstall and reinstall the browser and set the browser as default browser for any link to open. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

This question was asked a long time ago, but since there are no answers and this is a very annoying problem, here's a (frustratingly over-complicated) way to do this in Lotus Notes.

1. Right click on the email and select "Edit"
2. Right click on the link in question and select "HotSpot Properties"
3. A new box will pop up that has details about the link, you can now select the text in the "Value" field and Ctrl-C to copy the link address.

Hope this helps somebody down  the road looking for an answer!

Comment: I had to do step 1 multiple times in order to get the "HotSpot Properties" action, but it worked, thanks

Comment: Needed to open the e-mail in its own tab before the Edit option becomes available. Why do people still use this horrible software?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Lotus Notes is my mail client since more than 15 years now, and is has always been a big shit to work with (Though I'm working for the company which own this crap...).